# use FormValidator::Simple; causing Compilation failed

Tags: perl

```
[Fri Aug 12 11:39:54 2011] [error] [client 10.128.2.33] Global symbol "%Config" requires explicit package name at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/Time/Local.pm line 31.
[Fri Aug 12 11:39:54 2011] [error] [client 10.128.2.33] Global symbol "%Config" requires explicit package name at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/Time/Local.pm line 34.
[Fri Aug 12 11:39:54 2011] [error] [client 10.128.2.33] BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/Time/Local.pm line 57.
[Fri Aug 12 11:39:54 2011] [error] [client 10.128.2.33] Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/DateTime.pm line 47.
[Fri Aug 12 11:39:54 2011] [error] [client 10.128.2.33] BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/DateTime.pm line 47.
[Fri Aug 12 11:39:54 2011] [error] [client 10.128.2.33] Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Format/Strptime.pm line 8.
[Fri Aug 12 11:39:54 2011] [error] [client 10.128.2.33] BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/DateTime/Format/Strptime.pm line 8.
[Fri Aug 12 11:39:54 2011] [error] [client 10.128.2.33] Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/FormValidator/Simple/Validator.pm line 12.
[Fri Aug 12 11:39:54 2011] [error] [client 10.128.2.33] BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/FormValidator/Simple/Validator.pm line 12.
[Fri Aug 12 11:39:54 2011] [error] [client 10.128.2.33] Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/FormValidator/Simple/Constraint.pm line 5.
[Fri Aug 12 11:39:54 2011] [error] [client 10.128.2.33] BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/FormValidator/Simple/Constraint.pm line 5.
[Fri Aug 12 11:39:54 2011] [error] [client 10.128.2.33] Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/FormValidator/Simple/Profile.pm line 28.
[Fri Aug 12 11:39:54 2011] [error] [client 10.128.2.33] BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/FormValidator/Simple/Profile.pm line 28.
[Fri Aug 12 11:39:54 2011] [error] [client 10.128.2.33] Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/FormValidator/Simple.pm line 10.
[Fri Aug 12 11:39:54 2011] [error] [client 10.128.2.33] BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/FormValidator/Simple.pm line 10.
```

The above is the error stack of the line `use FormValidator::Simple;`,

Is there anyone that has met the same problem before?

Answer (score 2):

That error would happen if the Config module, a part of Perl, stopped exporting `%Config`.

I suspect you created a module named "Config" which is getting picked up by Time::Local instead of the module by the same name that's a part of Perl. Rename your module.